# react-native firebase DB - read node content

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

How do I output the value of a node?  I tried

```
let item = firebase.database().ref('maps/').child('redzone');
console.log(item.toJSON());
```

and

```
let item = firebase.database().ref('maps/').child('redzone');
console.log(JSON.stringify(item.toJSON()));
```

but every time I just get the firebase URL, not the actual object. How do I read it?

Comment: Have you tried firebase.database().ref('maps').child('redzone');?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of your code reads data fro the database yet. All it does is create a reference to a location in the database. To read data you have to use `on()` or `once()`. For example:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref('maps/').child('redzone');
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

This is all quite well covered in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) and [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) for web developers, so I recommend spending some time in those.